# jQuery UI autocomplete is not working after jQuery load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to use jQuery UI autocomplete function and it works great untill I replace data with jQuery load() function. After this nothing works - there is complete silence.

My html code looks like this:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
         <label for="search">Search: </label>
         <input id="search">
</div>
```

And my js code:

```
function enableAutocomplete(){
$( "#search" ).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.getJSON( "/Controller/search", {
            term: request.term
        }, response );
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        (...something going on here, doesn't matter...)

    }
});
}
```

}

After the load() returns successfully, I call enableAutocomplete() to bind once again the autocomplete event with my selected element. I've read somewhere on this forum, that I should do so. But since this time, nothing happens. The autocomplete is never called after typing. I debugged it in the console and record everything in the timeline(Chrome dev tools), and, like I said - there is complete silence. 
Does anybody have any idea, why??

Comment: could you show more of your code? like when are you calling the enableAutocomplete?

Comment: hi, thanks for reply :) I'm calling enableAutocomplete() twice: once in the $(function(){}) and second time in the success part of the load() function.

Comment: What does "/Controller/search" do? Try fixing [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dLxvS/) up and show us what is wrong.

Comment: Well, that is the call to the server-side action. It just returns the data in JSON format that are later displayed. This part works fine. The problem is in the frontend: why the $.getJSON is never called. And why it happens only after I call load() function first.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this

```
    function _debugResponse(respData,txt,xhr){console.log('Debug server response'); console.log(respData);}

function enableAutocomplete() {
  console.log('enableAutocomplete called');
  $("#search").autocomplete({
    source:    function (request, response) {
     console.log('autocomplete.source method called');
     $.getJSON("/Controller/search", { term: request.term }, _debugResponse );
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select:    function (event, ui) { console.log(event) }
  });
}                            

enableAutocomplete();
```

and post what do you get on the dev-console?

Comment: Hi, I tryed this, and here is what shows in the console: Before load(): enableAutocomplete called functions.js:134
autocomplete.source method called functions.js:150
Debug server response functions.js:518
[Object]
 functions.js:518      and after load():
enableAutocomplete called. So again - the source method is never called :/

Comment: I made a couple a minor modification to the code above.
1) source method will be called once you type at least 2 chars, that's when you check the network console to see what's being called.
2) Are you handling the "term" on the server side?
3) Are you returning a JSON object?
4) Can you tell me what do you get on the network console for the call?